# Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS stuck at bootscreen on Virtual Box 4.3.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, filesystems, bootloader

I had a running Ubuntu 12.04 VM on a Windows 7 host with Virtual Box 4.3.10 - until yesterday. Somehow, my host OS crashed and with it the still running VB.

Now, when I try to start the VM again, it gets stuck at boot time:
[image]

I can *not* change into tty by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and the like.

I managed to go into recovery mode by pressing Shift during boot. However, when I select one of the available options such as `clean` and run it, nothing really happens and this screen prevails:

[image]

What I can do now is Ctrl+C out and then I am in the root console. However, from there, I have no clue what I could do.

Seems to me like the VDI image is somehow broken.. what could I do?

This is the log of the VM: http://pastebin.com/sziRrnnJ (in line 1064 I suspended the machine)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the last output that is printed before the machine hangs is: 
"Checking battery state [ok]"

Googling this I found this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/205695/12-04-hangs-at-checking-battery-state

The third answer, concerned with nVidia drivers, did the trick for me:
`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-3*` and then
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and then
`sudo reboot`